# Hibernate and Spring integration error on connection pool and database creation

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to make a web application that integrates Spring and Hibernate. What I get is not an exception, but my log continues to generate messages that, in my opinion, underline a problem in the db generation\connection. I declared an hsql database that I can access by the hsql swing manager, but the db file is not visible in the file explorer. Instead of test.db I get the following files:

- testdb.lck
- testdb.log
- testdb.properties
- testdb.script

The log warning is the following message; googling around it seems not to be a problem, but the message are generated around every second, seeming to close all the connection pool and creating new istances:

```
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (BasicResourcePool.java:1550) - BEGIN check for expired resources.  [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@788c1852]
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (BasicResourcePool.java:1632) - EXPIRED idle resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@400ba6f6 ---> idle_time: 8513; max_idle_time: 7000 [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@788c1852]
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (BasicResourcePool.java:1561) - Removing expired resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@400ba6f6 [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@788c1852]
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:236) - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner@60eb9f58: Adding task to queue -- com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask@31b75e54
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (BasicResourcePool.java:1022) - Preparing to destroy resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@400ba6f6
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (BasicResourcePool.java:1747) - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@788c1852 [managed: 1, unused: 1, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@a62b39f)
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:616) - Preparing to destroy PooledConnection: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@400ba6f6
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (BasicResourcePool.java:1747) - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@788c1852 [managed: 1, unused: 1, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@a62b39f)
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (GooGooStatementCache.java:355) - ENTER METHOD: closeAll( org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@4795dda9 )! -- num_connections: 0
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (BasicResourcePool.java:1571) - FINISHED check for expired resources.  [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@788c1852]
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (GooGooStatementCache.java:394) - closeAll(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 0; checked out: 0; num connections: 0; num keys: 0
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (BasicResourcePool.java:450) - incremented pending_acquires: 1
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (NewPooledConnection.java:646) - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@400ba6f6 closed by a client.
java.lang.Exception: DEBUG -- CLOSE BY CLIENT STACK TRACE
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:646)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.closeMaybeCheckedOut(NewPooledConnection.java:259)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:619)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1024)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:627) - Successfully destroyed PooledConnection: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@400ba6f6
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (BasicResourcePool.java:1788) - Starting acquisition series. Incremented pending_acquires [1],  attempts_remaining: 30
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (BasicResourcePool.java:1027) - Successfully destroyed resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@400ba6f6
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:236) - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner@60eb9f58: Adding task to queue -- com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@7d91f64b
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (GooGooStatementCache.java:333) - checkinAll(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 0; checked out: 0; num connections: 0; num keys: 0
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:283) - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager@49833c9c.acquireResource() returning.
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (BasicResourcePool.java:1747) - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@788c1852 [managed: 2, unused: 2, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@a62b39f)
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (BasicResourcePool.java:471) - decremented pending_acquires: 0
17/06/2015 16:04:11 - DEBUG - (BasicResourcePool.java:1825) - Acquisition series terminated successfully. Decremented pending_acquires [0],  attempts_remaining: 30
```

This message seems to repeat endlessy.

My configuration files are:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Fantacalcio</display-name>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-database.xml,WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


</web-app>
```

spring-mvc-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
    <beans:bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.controller" />
</beans:beans>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\\hsqldb-2.3.2\\hsqldb\\test.db</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">SA</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">1000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>


        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">7</property> <!-- secondi -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property><!-- millisecondi -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout">2000</property><!-- millisecondi -->


        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>-->
        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>


        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>


        <mapping class="org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.model.beans.Utente"/>
        <mapping class="org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.model.beans.Ruolo"/>
        <mapping class="org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.model.beans.Calciatore"/>
        <mapping class="org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.model.beans.Formazione"/>
        <mapping class="org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.model.beans.Partita"/>
        <mapping class="org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.model.beans.Scontro"/>
        <mapping class="org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.model.beans.SquadraFantacalcio"/>
        <mapping class="org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.model.beans.SquadraReale"/>
        <mapping class="org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.model.beans.StagioneFantacalcio"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

spring-database.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Sorry for the code formatting but it seems not to like xml very much, hoping someone edits my message.

Comment: Have you actually looked at your logging? It isn't generating an error only a debug message.

Comment: ok, it isn't an error but the message alarms me a little bit. And the databasefile isn't generated.

Comment: For starters stop loading your application twice... You are loading the same configuration by the `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener` effectively loading your whole application twice. Next `testdb` and `test.db` aren't the same either a typo or you are pointing to the wrong file.

Comment: If I remove the `ContextLoaderListener` declaration in the web.xml the application starts but hibernate doesn't even try to create the db and spring does not instantiate beans. By the way the database name error was just a typo, every name I use leads to the generation of the files I said before but the database file is not generated.

Comment: Well obviously because you now only load the mvc stuff. You should remove the `WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xm` from the files that are loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`.

Comment: I don't think I understood you very well!

Comment: Your `ContextLoaderListener` is loading both the `/WEB-INF/spring-database.xml` and the `WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml`, the latter is already loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`. Hence loading everything twice.